# django Filtering data from multiple tables having no foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

> model.py

```
class Tas(models.Model):
tas_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
ware_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) 
taserid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)   
class Channels(models.Model):
taserid = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True) 
type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
displayname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True) 
class Ware(models.Model):
ware_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ware_name = models.CharField(null = False,max_length=255)
taserid = models.CharField(null = True, max_length=255)
```

> views.py

```
def index(request):
assert isinstance(request,HttpRequest)
display = Tas.objects.all(),
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select es.date,ew.ware_name,ec.type,ec.displayName from tas as es inner join
ware as ew on ew.ware_id = es.ware_id inner join channels as ec on ec.taserId = es.taserId")
```

> I am facing problem in applying filters because there is no foreign key between Task,Channels,Ware.
>   however there is a common field among these table.Please suggest how can i apply filter in sales table on the basis of Channels Table ---column type ,displayname and Tas Table--- column date

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make `ForeignKey`s from `taserid` in the `Ware` model, etc.?

Comment: If there is a common field you can use it in `JOIN` and `WHERE` operations. The foreign key is just a helper from the database management system, enforcing value constraints and usually indexing. Not at all required for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please suggest how can i apply filter in sales table on the basis of Channels Table ---column type ,displayname and Tas Table--- column date